# Brutal Doom v19-How do I see my health and ammo on the HUD?

Tags: doom

I installed Brutal Doom without an error with the Ultimate Doom (Steam) .wads. When I get into the game, it works perfectly fine, but I don't see my health or ammo. Is it a bug or in the menu? The menu in Brutal Doom is humongous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this mod you cannot see your health and ammo. However if it helps, when your health drops below 30% your screen will be stained. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I guess this is the best answer I will get, but to improve it, is there a mod for Brutal Doom that allows a HUD? If you can find one that works, +50 rep for you! :D

Comment: http://redd.it/1z14u9 Brutal doom with a custom HUD.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I also had to use the +/- keys to turn on the visor. Thanks a bunch! Enjoy your rep! :D

Answer (score -1):

One of the reasons I can't really stand Brutal Doom, even tho it does make it look prettier. Doom is all about managing your ammo and health, which you now cannot see. They also added the "you have to reload" feature, but you can't manually reload (even tho there's a keybinding for it in the options), and you can't see how much ammo you have left, so you either have to count every bullet or just hope that you won't run out in the middle of a fight.

Comment: So you're saying there's no way to see it?

Comment: This is just a kinda laid-back rant, not an answer.